# nodejs express: Setting express.static path as parent folder (/..) error

Tags: node.js, express, path

```
import express from "express"
import path from "path"

const app = express();
const __dirname = path.resolve();

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../'webapp_test`))   //ERROR

app.get(`/`,(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/../webapp_test/todo.html`);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

By setting express.static() path as string literal with escape sequence `${}`

Error occurs when connect to `localhost:8080` like

```
ForbiddenError: Forbidden
    at SendStream.error (WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\send\index.js:270:31)
    at SendStream.pipe (WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\send\index.js:553:12)
    at sendfile (WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1103:8)
    at ServerResponse.sendFile (WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:433:3)
    at file://WORKING DIRECTORY/main.js:13:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (WORKING DIRECTORYt\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at WORKING DIRECTORY\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

But if I set path with `path.join` method as

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,`..`,`webapp_test`));

app.get(`/`,(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,`..`,`webapp_test`,`todo.html`));
});
```

Page loads well

What am I missing?

Comment: const __dirname = path.resolve(); what is the purpose here its confusing me to use __dirname as const because its reserved one

Comment: I’ve set the type of js file as “module” to use ‘import’ instead of require.

Comment: By doing that, inorder to use __dirname, I have to set it as resolve method of path module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the "../". This is considered malicious and will be blocked by express in order to prevent web users from theoretically accessing the computers file system by typing .. In the url.
You need to resolve the path first by calling path.resolve and then the whole computers file s pass it to express.
This is essentially what path.join also does so that after calling path.join it also works.

That means you need to replace

```
res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/../webapp_test/todo.html`);
```

with

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../webapp_test/todo.html`));
```

As well as

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../'webapp_test`))   //ERROR
```

with

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(`${__dirname}/../webapp_test`)))   //ERROR
```

Another solution would be to specify the root directory for your calls like ths :

```
res.sendfile(path, {'root': '/path/to/root/directory'});
```

Hope that anwsers your question.